# Populate an array with objects in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I'm trying to an populate an invoiceForm that must contain an array of positions with a product on every position. I can't find the way how to populate product object in this formBuilder. The final object need to look like the JSON. The main problem is that on backend, product name and price are not recognized like, for example, quantity.

```
{
  "number": "number",
  "date": "2021-05-30",
  "thirdPartyPersonId": 4,
  "type": 0,
  "positions": [
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "First",
        "price": 1000
      },
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "name": "Second",
        "price": 100
      },
      "quantity": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      thirdPartyPersonId: 0,
      date: '',
      number: '',
      positions: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      productForm: this.formBuilder.group({
        name: '',
        price: 0,
      }),
      quantity: 0
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.positions = this.invoiceForm.get('positions') as FormArray;
    this.positions.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

`

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div>
    <input formControlName="thirdPartyPersonId">
    <input type="date" formControlName="date">
    <input formControlName="number">
</div>
<div formArrayName="positions">
    <div *ngFor="let item of invoiceForm.get('positions')['controls']; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input formControlName="productForm.name" placeholder="prod name">
            <input formControlName="productForm.price" placeholder="prod quantity">
            <input formControlName="quantity" placeholder="prod quantity">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
```

Comment: Do you need the `positions` array to be in order? I didn't quite follow it.

Comment: No, the problem is that when I post a new invoice, all the products from positions array are null.

Comment: You mean to say that when you send the data to backend it becomes null?

Comment: Yes, yes! Just product objects from positions array becomes null, all other information is ok. So, the main proble for me now is how to populate this product object, for example after submit, backend receive this JSON : {
  "number": "number",
  "date": "2021-05-30",
  "thirdPartyPersonId": 4,
  "type": 0,
  "positions": [
    {
      "product": null,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "product":null,
      "quantity": 80
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

When you use a reactive form you need to make sure that its structure matches the structure of the objects that you are creating/populating with.

The root cause of your problem was that in the FormArray items you were creating a `productForm` which was grouping nested controls, but in the template you were not creating that group. Simply referring by `productForm.name` won't work. You need to declare a group by using `formGroupName` or by providing an input with `[formGroup]`.

I stripped the form down to `positions` array and the code that works for me is:

##### html

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="positions">
    <div *ngFor="let item of invoicePositions.controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <ng-container formGroupName="product">
          <input formControlName="name" placeholder="prod name">
          <input formControlName="price" placeholder="prod quantity">
        </ng-container>
        <input formControlName="quantity" placeholder="prod quantity">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
</form>
```

##### ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-soform',
  templateUrl: './soform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./soform.component.css'],
})
export class SoformComponent implements OnInit {
  invoiceForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  get invoicePositions(){
    return this.invoiceForm.get('positions') as FormArray
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invoiceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      positions: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem(), this.createItem()]),
    });

    this.invoiceForm.setValue({
      positions: [
        {
          product: {
            name: 'First',
            price: 1000,
          },
          quantity: 2,
        },
        {
          product: {
            name: 'Second',
            price: 100,
          },
          quantity: 80,
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      product: this.formBuilder.group({
        name: '',
        price: 0,
      }),
      quantity: 0,
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    // this.positions = this.invoiceForm.get('positions') as FormArray;
    // this.positions.push(this.createItem());

    this.invoicePositions.push(this.createItem());
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.invoiceForm.value);
  }
}
```

##### console output

```
{
    "positions": [
        {
            "product": {
                "name": "First",
                "price": 1000
            },
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "product": {
                "name": "Second",
                "price": 100
            },
            "quantity": 80
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that I commented out two lines in `addItem` method - you don't need to assign anything to `this.positions` - it is enough to grab a reference of the FormArray, which we do by using a getter. This getter comes in handy in the template as well.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!